# Application deployment - asp.net mvc, windows service

Tags: deployment, setup-deployment

I've created an application that consists of a

- asp.net mvc 3 control panel
- windows service
- ms sql database

I would like to create an installer that is able to handle the deployment and auto updates of this application.

The application requires at least those things to be done during install:

- ensure MsSQL 2008 is installed (if not prompt the user or install express version)
- ensure user has Net Framework 4.0, ASP.NET MVC 3.0 installed (and probably some other Ms products I forgot)
- set appropriate connection strings in an xml configuration file
- add SQL Server user (the one that is used to run the instance) privileges to read/write to a folder
- create an IIS Site and application pool (and deploy the app)
- set the application pool mode to 4.0 Integrated
- create a windows service
- grant the asp.net application a privilege to control the mentioned windows service (subinacl /service service_name  /grant="IIS APPPOOL\DeployTest"=F)
- create the database, run create scripts
- create database users and grant them appropriate privileges
- edit web config file to set some custom settings

Is it at all possible? Or am I forced to do that manually?

Comment: Hi I need to install a service from the WebApp, is there a way to do it? How you ended doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and there're many ways and tools to achieve that.

Ultimately you can create a windows installer (msi) package which [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) can help.

Comment: Can you name just a few of these tools?

Comment: I've investigated the windows installer option (including WIX) and the problem is that windows installer does not support automatic updates.

Comment: After reading WIX tutorial - WIX is out of the question. It's complex, it provides nothing really useful in my situation.

Comment: [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) should be perfect to deploy the website and possible the database. MSBuild scripts can help deployment of windows services. [MSBuild Community Task](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) includes a XmlUpdate task to help updating the config files.

Comment: I can't use Web Deploy, because often I need to deploy to Windows Vista/Seven - it's impossible to enable WebDeploy on those systems (I've spent several days on this case)

Comment: I've been using Web Deploy on my windows 7 develop machine without problems. And you won't even need to install it on the target computer. Usually I simply pack the binaries into the deployment package and call it from batch scripts or MSBuild.

Comment: Thanks, I've used that previously, but it somehow didn't occur to me that I can just use it in the "local mode" (always thought about the remote that won't work on win7)- that way I can deploy database & mvc..